# Custom Function not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently developing a WordPress theme based on _s because the project is pretty different than average WordPress projects.

I started a few days ago and have done designing and now I am stuck in one place for hours.

I am trying to create a function to **generate video id from Youtube link** (a custom field does the job for 'video' post type).

The output is something like this: `a0uGWc170Jc`.

The code I used is below:

```
$id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_option_youtube-link', true);
$id = explode('?v=', $id);
if (empty($id[1])) {
    $id = explode('/v/', $id);
}
$id = explode("&", $id[1]);
$id = $id[0];
echo $id;
```

This code works well only when I add it inside of **WP Query**. I tried to make a function and inserted this function to theme's function.php file and tried to echo inside WP_Query but it returns php error. The function I made is:

```
function my_videoid() {
    $id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_option_youtube-link', true);
    $id = explode('?v=', $id);
    if (empty($id[1])) {
        $id = explode('/v/', $id);
    }
    $id = explode("&", $id[1]);
    $id = $id[0];
    return $id;
}
```

(also tried to echo instead of return)

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What WordPress hook are you calling this from, and what error are you getting?

Comment: I think You are doing it wrong. First you have to define 
     global $post;
 before get_post_meta to make it work .

Second you have to pass post id as an argument and have to use that id in get_post_meta in your function if you want to make it independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed the global $post, $wpdb;

Please try it.